# Wait until called jar execution finished

Tags: java

In my Java program, I start an external .jar file which modifies the system clipboard content. After that I continue with the data written to the clipboard. Unfortunately it looks like the jar gets started and the program doesn't wait until the jar execution is finished.

Here is the code I use to start the jar file:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class JarExecutor {

    private String pathToJar = "";
    private String jarFile = "";
    private String pathToJava = "C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\javaw.exe";

    public JarExecutor(String pathToJar, String jarFile) {
        this.pathToJar = pathToJar;
        this.jarFile = jarFile;
    }

    public void execute() {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pathToJava, "-jar", pathToJar + jarFile);
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And that's from the main program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pathToJar = "\\\\some\\net\path";
        String jarFile = "externalProgram.jar";

        JarExecutor myExecutor = new JarExecutor(pathToJar, jarFile)
        myExecutor.execute();

        [...]
}
```

As long as I put a `Thread.sleep(ms)` with ms > 3000 after the `myExecutor.execute()` in my program it works, but I guess that's no proper way to wait for the other process to be finished.

Comment: Did you consider using gradle instead? You can execute external java processes nicely there and you can put your own code there as well. If that could suit you, I can prepare an answer with example and references to docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right there in the [`Process` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--):

> **`waitFor`**
>
> ```
> public abstract int waitFor()
> throws InterruptedException
> ```
>
> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated. This method returns immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess exits.

Comment: Thanks
Works perfect now. I´ll add your answer to my question

Comment: @Moka: Don't do that, that's not how SO works. What you've done (marking the answer accepted) is how you do it here. Glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Using `waitFor` would be the perfect solution if you need the `main` to proceed only after the jar execution is done. Otherwise, you will be looking at some sort of interprocess communication. Try using sockets to pass messages between the processes.